# How to run a unittest method with Unicode characters in the name in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

when run a unittest method with Unicode characters,always present the 'Provide a qualified name of a function, class or module' warning.

In fact, Unicode characters are allowed as method names in Python.

Of course there is the option of manually clicking Run and then Continue Anyway to force it to run (and it actually does run successfully), but that's too tedious, is there a better way?

Is this a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug.
See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48747
Upvote the ticket and feel free to comment it.

Comment: I asked the same question in the IDEA forum, and after a long time no one seemed to reply, so I repeated it in StackOverFlow. Now IntelliJ IDEA staff submitted the issue for me directly.